# How to combine localhost codeigniter webapp files into a single installation file?

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Now its need to install xampp, import db, inset codeigniter file to xampp folder. Is that possible to combine all these steps to single like windows app installation file(.exe file).

Comment: Why would you need that? Isn't it better to let anyone use their own server setup, like a virtual machine on mac/linux and such?

Comment: You should simply put the code in a version control repo and use some database-migration library to handle the database. That could make it 100% platform independent.